# Pywinauto ItemStatusProperty selection

Tags: pywinauto

Is there a way for me to use pywinauto to select the UIA property ItemStatus.

I can see the property with the inspect.exe tool, but pywinauto elements don't have it exposed.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Too busy these days. It's possible to access this property using `.element_info` and something like `.CurrentItemStatus`. But need to re-check.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  I Will check and let you know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately,  .CurrentItemStatus is not part of ye list of attributes for .element_info. I tried to find other attributes that may help but still couldn't.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way,  but I used underlying element object to do this.

.element_info._element.CurrentItemStatus

This return the property value I needed.

Thanks for the element_info suggestion @vasily, that gave me the pointer where to look in the src code.